# What type of rounding is applied in the f-string formatting?

Tags: python, format, rounding, f-string

What type of rounding is applied in the f-string formatting below?

```
List = [0.0505, 0.0515, 0.0525, 0.0535, 0.0545, 
     0.0555, 0.0565, 0.0575, 0.0585, 0.0595]

print(['{:.3f}'.format(p) for p in List])

# result
# ['0.051', '0.051', '0.052', '0.053', '0.054', 
# '0.056', '0.057', '0.058', '0.059', '0.059']

# '''
# third decimal place

# number 0: 0 to 1
# -------------------------
# number 1: 1 in 1
# number 2: 2 in 2
# number 3: 3 in 3
# number 4: 4 in 4
# -------------------------
# number 5: 5 to 6
# number 6: 6 to 7
# number 7: 7 to 8
# number 8: 8 to 9
# -------------------------
# number 9: 9 in 9 

# '''
```

The symmetry seems to suggest a special type.

I expected a result like numpy.round(List,3)

array([0.05 , 0.052, 0.052, 0.054, 0.054, 0.056, 0.056, 0.058, 0.058, 0.06 ])

Comment: Floating point values aren't exact values. `0.0595` is more a `0.05949999999999999734`. Change your code to use `'{:.20f}'.format(p)` and look at the results. A must read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

In the f-string formatting you provided:

```
print(['{:.3f}'.format(p) for p in List])
```

The formatting is using **round half to even** rounding, which is also known as **banker's rounding** or **rounding to the nearest even number**.

Here's how it works with your example:

- 0.0505 is rounded to 0.051 because it's halfway between 0.050 and 0.051.
- 0.0515 is also rounded to 0.051 because it's closer to 0.051 than 0.052.
- 0.0525 is rounded to 0.052 because it's halfway between 0.052 and 0.053.
- 0.0535 is rounded to 0.054 because it's closer to 0.054 than 0.053.

The behavior you expected, similar to `numpy.round(List, 3)` which uses **conventional rounding**, would indeed give you different results. In conventional rounding, numbers are rounded up if the fractional part is greater than or equal to 0.5, and rounded down otherwise. This would result in the pattern you described in your expected result.

So, in summary, the f-string formatting is using round half to even (banker's rounding), not conventional rounding, which is why you're getting the results you observed.